# Trouble building Tensorflow 2.0 from source

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04, bazel, avx

I'm trying to push some tensorflow 2.0 models onto an Ubuntu 18.04 server. The server's cpu's don't support AVX, so as per the community on github, I'll need to build from source to build tf 2.0 without AVX. I've spent a week trying to build from source, and the build complete's successfully, but I still keep getting the same "Illegal Instruction" error when trying to import tensorflow into a python notebook.

I'm running python 3.6 on Ubuntu 18.04

the bazel configuration is with XLA and JIT but and No to the remaining options.

copt flags I'm using are:

```
-march=native -Wno-sign-compare -mssse3 -mcx16 -msse4.1 -msse4.2 -mpopcnt -mno-avx
```

The build command is:

```
bazel build --config=opt  //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package --local_ram_resources=1024 --jobs=1 --define=tf_api_version=2
```

the server's CPU's are:

```
sudo lshw | grep -i cpu

     *-cpu:0
          description: CPU
          product: QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.5+
          bus info: cpu@0
          slot: CPU 0
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx x86-64 rep_good nopl xtopology cpuid pni cx16 x2apic hypervisor lahf_lm pti
     *-cpu:1
          description: CPU
          product: QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.5+
          bus info: cpu@1
          slot: CPU 1
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx x86-64 rep_good nopl xtopology cpuid pni cx16 x2apic hypervisor lahf_lm pti
     *-cpu:2
          description: CPU
          product: QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.5+
          bus info: cpu@2
          slot: CPU 2
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx x86-64 rep_good nopl xtopology cpuid pni cx16 x2apic hypervisor lahf_lm pti
     *-cpu:3
          description: CPU
          product: QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.5+
          bus info: cpu@3
          slot: CPU 3
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx x86-64 rep_good nopl xtopology cpuid pni cx16 x2apic hypervisor lahf_lm pti
```

This is the first time I've had to dig so deeply into questions of hardware and I'm at a loss.

Firstly, is it possible to build tensorflow to run on a QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.5+?

Secondly, if so, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: After adding `-march=native` do not add any further `-m*` flags. Your virtual cpu seems not to support SSE3 or SSE4.x. You could also try to configure QEMU to emulate a CPU which supports AVX (or higher SSE versions).

Comment: @chtz, Thanks. Actually, the command that I show above ended up working. the issue turned out to be due to sporadic failures on account of limited memory as the server only has 4GB and the --local-ram-resources flag apparently doesn't work when multiple jobs are running.